# Gatsby JS Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Can someone help me please. I'm using a Gatsby Template that was using an old version of react. I'm using this navbar component, which works fine for the original template. Now I'm trying to use it in my project, however I keep getting this problem, I'm new to React, can someone please help me, or even help me restruct this component to make it more updated to today's versions of React. Please & Thank You ahead

This is my Navbar Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import AnchorLink from "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll"
import Scrollspy from "react-scrollspy"
import { Container } from "@components/global"
import {
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  Brand,
  StyledContainer,
  NavListWrapper,
  MobileMenu,
  Mobile,
} from "./style"

import { ReactComponent as MenuIcon } from "@static/icons/menu.svg"

const NAV_ITEMS = ["About", "Brands", "Team", "FAQ"]

class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {
    mobileMenuOpen: false,
  }

  toggleMobileMenu = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ mobileMenuOpen: !prevState.mobileMenuOpen }))
  }

  closeMobileMenu = () => {
    if (this.state.mobileMenuOpen) {
      this.setState({ mobileMenuOpen: false })
    }
  }

  getNavAnchorLink = item => (
    <AnchorLink href={`#${item.toLowerCase()}`} onClick={this.closeMobileMenu}>
      {item}
    </AnchorLink>
  )

  getNavList = ({ mobile = false }) => (
    <NavListWrapper mobile={mobile}>
      <Scrollspy
        items={NAV_ITEMS.map(item => item.toLowerCase())}
        currentClassName="active"
        mobile={mobile}
        offset={-64}
      >
        {NAV_ITEMS.map(navItem => (
          <NavItem key={navItem}>{this.getNavAnchorLink(navItem)}</NavItem>
        ))}
      </Scrollspy>
    </NavListWrapper>
  )

  render() {
    const { mobileMenuOpen } = this.state

    return (
      <Nav {...this.props}>
        <StyledContainer>
          <Brand>Absurd</Brand>
          <Mobile>
            <button onClick={this.toggleMobileMenu} style={{ color: "black" }}>
              <MenuIcon />
            </button>
          </Mobile>

          <Mobile hide>{this.getNavList({})}</Mobile>
        </StyledContainer>
        <Mobile>
          {mobileMenuOpen && (
            <MobileMenu>
              <Container>{this.getNavList({ mobile: true })}</Container>
            </MobileMenu>
          )}
        </Mobile>
      </Nav>
    )
  }
}

export default Navbar
```

This is my index.js for Navbar

```
export { default } from "./Navbar"
```

And this is where I'm using the Navbar Component

```
import React from "react"

import Layout from "@common/layout"
import Navbar from "@common/Navbar"

import Header from "@sections/Header"
import About from "@sections/About"
import Team from "@sections/Team"
import Faq from "@sections/Faq"
import Footer from "@sections/Footer"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Navbar />
    <Header />
    <About />
    <Team />
    <Faq />
    <Footer />
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

For some reason I'm getting this error:
[Error shown in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9jAi.png)

Answer (score 0):

React components must be capitalized, otherwise, are interpreted by a markup tag. In your case, I think you may want to use something similar to:

```
export Navbar from "./Navbar"
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
export { default as Navbar } from "./Navbar"
```

For a more succinct approach.